# React native 0.69.1 borderRadius not working properly from top it not show border css

Tags: javascript, css, react-native, styles, styled-components

**I made a view in the screen where I gave `borderRadius:20` to view
border-radius on the top edges is not showing**

> I don't know why this is not working

```
<View style={{height:200,width:200,bordeRadius:20,alignItems:"center"}}>
<Text>xyz</Text>
</View>
```

Answer (score 0):

**According to docs, you might need to apply overflow: 'hidden' .**

> https://reactnative.dev/docs/view-style-props
>
> overflow: 'hidden'

```
  <View style={{height:200,width:200,bordeRadius:20,overflow:'hidden',alignItems:"center}}>
    <Text>xyz</Text>
    </View>
```